# How to remove last border of breadcrumb

Tags: html, css

How to remove last border of breadcrumbs .I am attaching plunkr link
I need to remove the border like image.please find the attached image and plunkr link.Arrow breadcrumb  with white background and blue border.

[image]

[plunkr link breadcrumb](https://plnkr.co/edit/gMEYlc?p=preview)

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0174DF;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 13px 25px 13px 10px;
}

span:after,
span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  left: -25px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  border: 24px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 0 !important;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
}

span:before {
  left: -26px;
  border: 24px solid #0174DF;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>  Home </span></li>
  <li><span>  about </span></li>
  <li><span>  History </span></li>
  <li><span>  contact us </span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  ul{
  padding:0;
  font-size:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #0174DF;
   border-right:none;
  <!--   blue -->
}
 li{
  display:inline-block;
}
span{
  font-size:1rem;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  padding:13px 25px 13px 10px;
}
 span:after,
 span:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  height:0;
  width:1px;
  top:50%;
  left:-25px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  border:      24px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 0 !important;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
}
 span:before{
  left:-26px;
  border: 24px solid #0174DF;
}
```

```html
    <div style="display:flex">
    <ul>
        <li><<span>  Home </span></li>
        <li><<span>  about </span></li>
         <li><<span>  History </span></li>

      </ul>
        <span>  contact us </span>
       </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Tell me if u need help

Comment: @gyanendra do it helps u?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [Plunker preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Q2VthWgk78e3ooCgUvC?p=preview)

I took a different approach and made the span's pseudo elements a 45deg rotated cube with 2 sides of borders to represent the arrow shapes. Then hid the last span's pseudo element as you wished.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
   background: white;
  }

  ul {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   border-left: 1px solid #0174DF;
   background: white;
  }

  li {
   display: inline-block;
   border-top: 1px solid #0174DF;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #0174DF;
  }

  li:last-child {
   border: none;
  }

  span {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 1rem;
   position: relative;
   background: transparent;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   padding: 13px 10px 13px 35px;
  }

  li:first-child span {
   padding-left: 10px;
  }

  span::before {
   content: '';
   height: 33.5px;
   width: 33.5px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -1px;
   right: -17px;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
   background: transparent;
   border-top: 1px solid #0174DF;
   border-right: 1px solid #0174DF;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  li:last-child span::before {
   display: none;
  }


 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <ul>
  <li><span> Home </span></li><li><span> About </span></li><li><span> History </span></li><li><span> Contact us </span></li>
 </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not waht he wants look at the picure

Comment: I updated my answer with a correct version. It seems that I misunderstood his question before.

Answer (score 0):

```
li:last-child{
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Comment: position absolute adjust the 'li' position and hide the extra lines.